# Taking advantage of voter availability

Tags: discussion, voting

It is fairly clear that there are users here from various time zones. With different groups having different times of sleeping, working, etc. there are times when you can predict fairly well which users will be around.

Suppose there is something to be voted on, e.g. closing or reopening questions. Suppose as well that you can predict with some level of accuracy how various users would vote.

Suppose further that there is some level of correlation between the first two suppositions. That is to say that the users who you predict would agree with you are around at a specific time, and the users you predict would disagree with you are around at a specific other time.

How, if at all, can/should this information be taken into account when deciding *when* to bring up the vote?

(I imagine that it some cases it's important for the issue to be raised immediately, but in other cases a few hours doesn't seem so important.)

Comment: It shouldn't be used _at all_. As soon as you start trying to vote with others and voting based on other users you're doing something wrong.

Comment: If you're talking about policy decisions on meta here, these things aren't decided overnight. We'd wait for a suitable period of time before any policy is written to canons and put to work. Hence, I don't quite understand how one can take advantage of different users' being in different time zones.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I was mostly thinking of closing/reopening questions. As soon as there are five votes it leaves the queue, and anyone who wasn't there at the time won't know that anything took place unless they manually check histories, or just happen too come across the post.

Comment: Sure, that may happen, but it'd still get fixed in time, e.g. when a mod wakes up and walks by, or when someone posts on meta about it. Or when it's brought up in chat.

Comment: @Alex - There are a reasonable number of users who review pretty much every main site action, especially questions posted, closed, duplicated, etc

Comment: @Valorum You mean they manually review the histories?

Comment: @Alex - Sure. I can't speak for others but I tend to keep a left eye on every question that gets posted. If it gets closed or dropped into the review queue, I'll see what's happening with it.

Comment: @Valorum Nice dedication.

Comment: @Valorum you sure aren’t the only one. I tend to see most of what goes on when I’m around too.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Aye, and I'd expect the likes of Edlothiad and Fuzzy to fall into that category as well. The place is a panopticon if you want it to be

Comment: @Valorum guilty!

Comment: I don't even have VTC but I refresh the page many times throughout the day and see what happens to questions. Aside from all of that, even if the asker of an on-hold question doesn't come to the meta to clarify why their question is on hold, if it seems sketchy, a third party will often ask on meta about an on-hold question (or recently re-opened question). I've noticed up and down votes having peak hours, but I haven't really seen those peak hours having an effect on whether questions are closed or left open or re-opened. It all tends to come out in the wash, from what I've seen.

Answer (score 14):

**This smells too much like 'gaming the system'.**

Votes for closing or reopening are supposed to be based on community policies - these questions are on-topic, those questions are off-topic, maybe there's some grey areas which are worth discussing more. (This is in contrast with upvotes and downvotes, which may be based on personal preference.) If a question should be closed or reopened, then **it shouldn't matter who's voting** since all votes should be cast based on site scope rules rather than whether a particular user likes or dislikes a question. If it does matter - if there's evidence that particular users are abusing their close/reopen votes against policy - then mods can take action if necessary.

If there's a question you'd like to discuss with particular users before voting - experts in the tag, for example - then you might be interested in their activity hours so that you can ping them at the right time. But deciding when to vote just so that you can do it at a time when "users who agree with you" are online ... doesn't feel right. Even if it succeeds in getting a question closed/reopened, the "users who disagree with you" can always vote to reopen/close it again when they're online.

Comment: *Even if it succeeds in getting a question closed/reopened, the "users who disagree with you" can always vote to reopen/close it again when they're online.* If it's no longer in the review queue they would have to either manually notice it or check the review histories regularly, no?

Comment: @Alex or maybe just keep track of the close/reopen votes of people who instigated the present meta... :p

Comment: @Jenayah As far as I know, you can only do that by constantly checking the review history.

Comment: @Alex [for instance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum?tab=activity)

Comment: @Jenayah So you actually can see people's voting history. Interesting.

Comment: @Alex as far as I know, the SE profile page displays every action you ever made on the site, except _what_ you up- or down- voted (it displays the stats of  casted votes though). Just have to find the right tab or tweak, but yeah, you can basically stalk someone.

Comment: @Alex No, votes (up, down, close, reopen, delete, undelete) aren't publicly visible in account history. Unless they're accompanied by comments, of course. And close/reopen votes become visible if you're successful.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I can see Valorum's close/reopen votes in Jenayah's link.

Comment: @Alex Huh, where? [Reviews](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum?tab=activity&sort=reviews), yes, but not all votes are cast through review.

Comment: @Randal'Thor True, I can only see the ones from review.

Comment: @Jenayah Which means you wouldn't be able to see the instigator who presumably did not vote from Review.

Comment: @Alex ah, indeed, my bad - what about SEDE? If you're willing to stalk, maybe you can patch up something there, dunno how it works. But this is starting to get creepy :p

Comment: Can mods really take action? I thought the worst you can do is remove them from the queues for 7 days.